# Getting a 3d linear equation knowing the rotation of an object

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d, rotations

I have an object, a simple rectangle

I rotate it by a certain degree using Euler Angles, in this case around Z, to make it easy lets say it's 45 degrees.

Right now I want the yellow: Y-Axis linear equation so looking at the world axes and knowing I rotated it 45 degrees clockwise:

[image: http://s23.postimg.org/61ivhzvzv/rect1_rot1_Z45_2.png]

I use the $b = tan(rZ = 45)$ to get the equation $ay + bx + c$ where $a$ equals $1$ (I only need the dependency between $y$ and $x$ so I can just say that $a$ equals $1$), $b$ would equal $1$ in this case.

And so now I rotate the rectangle around its local blue X-Axis, again 45 degrees:

[image: http://s10.postimg.org/w8fxpda09/rect1_rot2_Y45.png]

And I need the 3d linear equation for the yellow Y-Axis, $ay + bx + cz + d$. Just like in the previous equation I can just state that one of the variables equals $1$. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For two points $p_1$ and $p_2$, a possible form of an equation of line that passes through them is

$$f(t) = t \cdot p_1 + (1-t) \cdot p_2. \tag{$\spadesuit$}$$

The only thing that matters is that $p_1 \neq p_2$, so put your two points where you want them (to form the yellow line) and rotate them together with the rectangle, just like any other points, $\spadesuit$ will still describe the line you are looking for.

I hope this helps ;-)

Comment: I'll try it out, and thanks for placing the images correctly.

Comment: Don't I need a function of x,y,z here? I'm not sure what to do with only one parameter when I have a point in three dimensions.

Hope you can excuse my stupidity, I haven't done math in a million years, and even the simplest function gives me a headache.

Comment: @Mac $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^3$. Line is one-dimensional (also rectangle is two-dimensional, cube is three-dimensional), so the input is $\mathbb{R}^1$, while the output is $\mathbb{R}^3$, i.e. the usual 3D space. That is, $p_1 = (x,y,z)$ and $t \cdot p_1$ means $(t \cdot x, t \cdot y, t\cdot z)$.

Comment: If the input is in $R^1$ I understand that I should calculate the f(x), f(y) and f(z) and in theory I will get 3 equations, but what is on the right side, a 0? Once again I apologise for my lack of understanding, I'm generaly an example learner so it would be way easier for me to understand this on a simple example like p1(1,1,1) and p2(-1,-1,-1).

Comment: @Mac Normally you have an equation like $x+y=1$ or like $y = 1 -x$. However, the very same line can be described as $f(t) = (t,1-t)$ or as $f(s) = (1-s,s)$ or as $f(r) = (r^{2013}-42,43-r^{2013})$. Observe that, whatever the definition, we have that result of $f$ satisfies the condition $x+y = 1$ or $y = 1-x$. You can find some more info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation).

Comment: Ok. Thank you, I am really grateful for your help!